# PHPmailer: Error: You must provide at least one recipient email address

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I know there is several similar threads but I have tried all without any success.

```
$recipient = ($_POST["to"]);
$mail->AddAddress = ($recipient);
```

This doesn't work. I have tried with many different combinations as well, like this:

```
$mail->addAddress = ($recipient, 'name');
```

I am also running the validate address, which returns true

```
var_dump(PHPMailer::validateAddress($recipient));
```

Still I am getting `Error: You must provide at least one recipient email address`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Curious as to why the brackets around things, ($_POST["to"]) ?

Comment: $mail->addAddress = ($recipient, 'name'); - change to $mail->addAddress($recipient, 'name');

Comment: I've seen this exact error before, which makes me suspect there's a page somewhere giving bad advice - can you provide me with a link to where you found this code?

Comment: I don't remember which one but it was certainly stackoverflow :p

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output
$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'mail.mysite.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'info@mysite.nl';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secure123'; //  SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to
$mail->setFrom('info@mysite.nl', 'My cool website');  // The email address of your site goes here
$mail->addAddress('customer@hotmail.com', 'Important customer');     //Destination address and name

$mail->Subject = 'Just saying hi!'; //Title of your mail
$mail->Body    = '<h1> A test mail </h1>';
$mail->AltBody = 'Mail has been sent!';
if(!$mail->send()) {
    $data = array('mailissend' => false, 'message' => $mail->ErrorInfo);

} else {
    echo json_encode('Email is sended');
}
```